# Checking/testing bilinearity of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, bilinear-form

I have already aware of the bilinear form of a function which is:

> $$<x,y> =x^tAy= \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} x_i y_j$$

Applying this concept to an example:

> $$ α(x,y)= \ x^T \begin{bmatrix}  2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1  \\  \end{bmatrix} y $$

Assuming

$$x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & y_1 \end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$y = \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Solving the equation yields:

> $$ α(x,y) = 2 x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2 -x_1 y_2 + y_1 y_2 $$

Now from this information how to ascertain whether the function is bilinear or not?
I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: welcome to MSE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a link to writing math with Math Jax

Comment: A function is bilinear if and only if it is linear in both of its arguments.

Here the arguments are $x$ and $y$  - so simply check if you fix x (or y respectively) is $\alpha$ linear? In other words, what you need to check is if $$\alpha(\lambda x, y) = \lambda \alpha (x, y) \quad \mbox{and}\quad \alpha(x + x', y) = \alpha (x, y) + \alpha(x', y)$$  meaning $\alpha$ is linear with respect to $x$. Calculate both sides of these equations and do this for $y$ as well. If equality holds indeed in these equations, $\alpha$ is bilinear indeed.

Comment: It is somewhat faster to check if $$\alpha(x + \lambda x', y) = \alpha (x, y) +\lambda \alpha(x',y)$$ This comes is the same as the two equations above compressed into one: to "compress" them chose $x'$ of the second equation to be $\lambda x'$ and then use the first equation to get the $\lambda$ out of the parentheses. To "decompress" choose $x$ and $x'$  respectively to be the zero vector to get the first and second equation from above respectively.

Comment: I also recommend using either, lets say, $a = \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\end{pmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{pmatrix}x_2\\y_2\end{pmatrix}$; or (I prefer this one) $x = \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}$ to avoid confusion later on.

Comment: Sorry, in my second comment, when I wrote: "To "decompress" choose $x$ and $x′$ respectively to be the zero vector to get the first and second equation from above respectively." I meant:

To "decompress" choose $x$ to be the zero vector to get the first and $\lambda =1$ to get the second equation from above respectively.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Fox for your detailed explanation.